# Further group by WEEK NUMBER in sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to subtract values from 2 columns and group them week number.
The event code column has values 3,4. I am trying to sum duration for event codes 4 and subtract the duration of event code 3. These values need to be derived for the last 12 weeks.

Here is what I have so far. I am stuff and further grouping by week number:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID,
((SELECT SUM(DURATION_IN_SECONDS)/60 FROM TABLE1 ee WHERE ee.CUSTOMER_ID = e.CUSTOMER_ID AND EVENT_CODE IN (4))-
(SELECT SUM(DURATION_IN_SECONDS)/60 FROM TABLE1 ee WHERE ee.CUSTOMER_ID = e.CUSTOMER_ID AND EVENT_CODE IN (3))) AS UNPRODUCTIVE_MINUTES
FROM  TABLE1 e
WHERE TIMEDATE >= TO_DATE('01-OCT-19','DD-MON-YY') 
AND TIMEDATE <= TO_DATE('31-DEC-19','DD-MON-YY')
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

The above query produces results like this:

```
CUSTOMER_ID   UNPRODUCTIVE_MINUTES
A100          1601
```

But my result has to be like this:

```
CUSTOMER_ID       WEEKNUMBER  UNPRODUCTIVE_MINUTES
A100              12            171
A100              11            108
A100              10            112
A100              9             110
A100              8             98
A100              7             67
A100              6             117
A100              5             100
A100              4             111
A100              3             77
A100              2             73
A100              1             87
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, how you want to calculate the week number but I guess weeknumber is `(timedate - start timedate / 7) + 1` so creating the query accordingly.

```
Select customer_id,
       Sum(case when EVENT_CODE = 4 then DURATION_IN_SECONDS else (-1* DURATION_IN_SECONDS) end)/60 as dur,
       Floor(Trunc(timedate) - TO_DATE('01-OCT-19','DD-MON-YY') / 7) + 1 as weeknumber
  From table1 e
 Where TIMEDATE >= TO_DATE('01-OCT-19','DD-MON-YY') 
   AND TIMEDATE <= TO_DATE('31-DEC-19','DD-MON-YY')
   AND EVENT_CODE in (3, 4)
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, floor(trunc(timedate) - TO_DATE('01-OCT-19','DD-MON-YY') / 7) + 1
```

Here, I have not used `event_code` 3 as `DURATION_IN_SECONDS` for `event_code` 3 and 4 both minus `DURATION_IN_SECONDS` for 3 will eventually same as `DURATION_IN_SECONDS` for `event_code` 4 alone.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you @Tejash. It has to be sum of duration for event code 4 - sum of duration for event code 3.

Answer (score 0):

- `TO_CHAR(TIMEDATE, 'ww')` function might directly be used to
  determine the week number
- No need to use `Correlated Subqueries`, but `Conditional Aggregation`
  should be used instead
- Reformat your `DATE` literals as `DATE'yyyy-mm-dd'` according to ISO standard as in the below
- Using BETWEEN Operator is enough for inclusive date ranges instead of
  inequalities

  query

  ```
  SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
         TO_CHAR(TIMEDATE, 'ww') AS WEEK,
         NVL(SUM(CASE
                   WHEN EVENT_CODE = 4 THEN
                    DURATION_IN_SECONDS / 60
                 END),
             0) - NVL(SUM(CASE
                            WHEN EVENT_CODE = 3 THEN
                             DURATION_IN_SECONDS / 60
                          END),
                      0) AS UNPRODUCTIVE_MINUTES
    FROM TABLE1 e
   WHERE TIMEDATE BETWEEN DATE '2019-10-01' AND DATE '2019-12-31'
   GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, TO_CHAR(TIMEDATE, 'ww')
   ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID, WEEK
  ```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=386a9123fcb96b38cac85b11e051056d)</kbd>